# Zooming on content view inside of scrollview doesn't work

Tags: ios, cocoa

I'm creating a scrollview with content view inside of it. inside of the content view there are buttons.

from this point, i already can zoom and pan on content view. but when the touch happen on a button the scrollview doesn't zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem and solved it with the following steps :

1. Create a UIView.
2. Create a UITapGestureRecognizer
3. Add the UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIView to handle taps.
4. Create a UIButton.
5. Disable User Interaction (`isUserInteractionEnabled = false`) on the button.
6. Add the UIButton as a SubView of the UIView.
7. In the UITapGestureRecognizer tapped selector, handle the UIButton touchesUpInside call.
8. Add the first UIView into the UIScrollView.
9. Make sure the UIScrollView delay content touches `delaysContentTouches = true`

The UIScrollView should be able to now seamlessly zoom and you can respond to your buttons.

You can skip the button altogether if you want and just handle the Tap in the Gesture Recognizer. I had to do it the way above because the buttons were a custom sub classed buttons and had a lot of additional custom rendering and functionality included.

Comment: @mol you are welcome! Can you please upvote the answer. Thanks :)